# Java - Trying to conduct a coin toss script with summary results of 10 coin toss

Tags: java

I'm  trying to write a script that will give me a summary of 10 coin toss. I'm stuck on how can I read the result and output as a summary something like this:

> C:\Users\javauser\Desktop> java CoinToss
>   Heads: 3
>   Tails: 7

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class CoinToss{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0)
                System.out.println("Tails");
            else
                System.out.println("Heads");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create two int variables to store the times that you got heads and the times that you got tails.After the end of the for loop just print the two variables.

Comment: @ericrk00 I see you changed your output order, my answer accounted for your original post pre-edited, but can be modified to suit your needs.

Comment: Which language are you trying to write your script in and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the result of your simulation.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class CoinToss{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Random rand = new Random();
      int numHeads = 0;
      int numTails = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0)
                numTails++;
            else
                numHeads++;
        }
        System.out.println("Heads: " + numHeads);
        System.out.println("Tails: " + numTails);
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are highly discouraged. Please explain the problem and/or your solution.

Comment: @Turing85 "Highly discouraged"? [Citation needed]. Besides that fact, this code is about as simple as it gets without adding inane comments like `i++; // increment the value of i`.

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Even if the problem seems trivial, OP struggels with it indicating that it is not trivial for him/her. Therefore, any kind of explanation might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of the results instead of printing right away, then print out the end results. I used String format here to keep the String clean from concatenation.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class CoinToss{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int heads = 0;
        int tails = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0)
                tails++;
            else
                heads++;
        }
        String results = String.format("CoinToss Heads: %d Tails: %d", heads, tails);
        System.out.printLn(results);
    }
}
```